# Do not add entries with duplicate names

Tags: php, mysql

Hello there is such a code

```
if(isset($_POST['add_product'])){
$req_fields = array('product-title','product-categorie','product-
quantity','buying-price', 'saleing-price' );
validate_fields($req_fields);
if(empty($errors)){
 $p_name  = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['product-title']));
 $p_cat   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['product-categorie']));
 $p_qty   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['product-quantity']));    
 $p_buy   = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['buying-price']));
 $total   = $p_qty*$p_buy ;
 $p_sale  = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['saleing-price']));
 if (is_null($_POST['product-photo']) || $_POST['product-photo'] === "") {
   $media_id = '0';
 } else {
   $media_id = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['product-photo']));
 }
 $date    = make_date();
 $query  = "INSERT INTO products (";
 $query .=" name,quantity,buy_price,total,sale_price,categorie_id,media_id,date";
 $query .=") VALUES (";
 $query .=" '{$p_name}', '{$p_qty}', '{$p_buy}', '{$total}', '{$p_sale}', '{$p_cat}', '{$media_id}', '{$date}'";
 $query .=")";
 $query .=" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='{$p_name}'";
 if($db->query($query)){
   $session->msg('s',"Готовый продукт добавлен в базу ");
   redirect('add_product.php', false);
 } else {
   $session->msg('d',' Ошибка  что то пошло не так!');
   redirect('product.php', false);
 }

} else{
 $session->msg("d", $errors);
 redirect('add_product.php',false);
}

 }
```

You can see that the code takes the form data and inserts it into the products table. All anything, but when the product names are duplicated from the p_name field, it does not add data to the table, but writes that "The finished product is added to the database". For example, in the database there is a product "Bread" added yesterday. If today we add the product with the name "Bread" again, it says "The finished product is added to the database", but it does not add anything. I feel that the line is all to blame. = "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = '{$ p_name}'"; But if you remove it, the script does not work.

Comment: Why you say the script does not work if you remove the "ON DUPLICATE"? can you explain this better? Because you need to remove that line of your code in order to accomplish the goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = '{$ p_name}` just erase this line of your code:

```
 $query .=" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='{$p_name}'";
```

**Note:** You are right, the problem is happening because you have ON `DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name = '{$ p_name}`. If you have "Bread" already on your **table** and try to **insert** another "Bread" you will never have 2 **products** called "Bread" because you are forcing the update of the existing (old) "Bread" product with the information provided by the "new" "Bread" product.

> I feel that the line is all to blame. = "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name
>   = '{$ p_name}'"; But if you remove it, the script does not work.

If the **script** is not working after you erase the **"ON DUPLICATE"** code line is because you probably have **name field** as **primary key** on your products **table**. If this is true you must create a compound primary key with the **name field + another field** (it can be an Id) instead of having only **name field** as **primary key**